# extending $rootScope.$broadcast in an iframe

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to solve the problem where I have a page built with AngularJS and a feature that requires a same domain iframe that is also angular.

What I'd like to achieve is broadcasting a message from the iframe using $rootScope.$broadcast to make it's way up to the parent frame.

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
app.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$rootScope', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
        var native = $delegate.$broadcast;
        $delegate.$broadcast = function (name, args) {
            if (window.frameElement) {
                console.log("Broadcast inside a frame");
                // Here I would do window.postMessage
            } else {
                console.log("Broadcast outside a frame");
            }
            return native;
        }
    return $delegate;
}]);
```

But this blows up with an angular error. Any suggestions on fixing this error? Is there a better way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: _Please define "blows up"_ What is the error?  How about this way? http://plnkr.co/edit/B70D8S?p=preview

Comment: I get an error saying Cannot read property '$$listeners' of undefined. I think it's because $broadcast uses 'this' and setting native = $delegate.$broadcast is changing the context of this inside $broadcast

Comment: Your plunker seems to break the $rootScope.$on scenario. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/R8RYTlye3oIHFiP5KaFP I think what's needed is saving the oldbroadcast message to the $delegate object and calling that. Any reason that could be a bad idea?

Comment: @Valchris Yes, there wont be any context when you do pass in the function reference of `$delegate.$broadcast`. ANd yes you need to do that. How ever i could not replicate that scenario though. Anyways if that is the issue why dont you just make it a bound function. `oldbroadcast  = $delegate.$broadcast.bind($delegate)` or `oldbroadcast  =angular.bind($delegate.$broadcast, $delegate)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are after. You were right about the problem being with the value of 'this', storing the $broadcast copy onto $delegate seems to do the trick

http://plnkr.co/edit/KW3whFtuu9C9Tvjo4kdS?p=preview

```
app.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {

   $provide.decorator('$rootScope', ['$delegate', '$window', function ($delegate, $window) {

     $delegate.native = angular.copy($delegate.$broadcast);

     $delegate.$broadcast = function (name, args) {

       if ($window.parent) {
            $window.parent.postMessage(args, '*');
            console.log("Broadcast inside a frame");
            // Here I would do window.postMessage
        } else {
            console.log("Broadcast outside a frame");
        }

        $delegate.native(name, args);

        return $delegate.native;
    }

   return $delegate;

  }]);

}]);
```

This is another way to do the same thing. (I left it here as it was my original answer before I got the decorator version working.)

http://plnkr.co/edit/s5qNtva1l0SJVV2y0Onk?p=preview

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $window){

    $rootScope.oldBroadcast = angular.copy($rootScope.$broadcast);

    $rootScope.$broadcast = function (name, args) {

        if ($window.parent) {
            $window.parent.postMessage(args, '*');
            console.log("Broadcast inside a frame", name, args);
            // Here I would do window.postMessage
        } else {
            console.log("Broadcast outside a frame");
        }

        $rootScope.oldBroadcast(name, args);

        return $rootScope.oldBroadcast;

    }

});
```